# maven executable jar with fxml files in javaFX

Tags: java, maven, jar, javafx, fxml

I want to create a executable jar. I read how to make a MANIFEST.MF, but I read with maven is pretty much easier:

http://www.springone2gx.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2008/06/creating_executable_jars_using_the_maven_assembly_plugin

but that solution doesn't include the fxml files.

Do you know a plugin for that or some tutorial that explain how and where I should insert the fxml files.

I noted that solution doesn't include gif or other file to jar too. So, I think that the should be a same solution to include other types of files to jar.

I'm near to deadline (yesterday). So any help that permit me make it in 5 min (anyone can dream) will be more than welcome.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Zenjava-Javafx-maven-plugin` for this. Just add this to your `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>your.package.with.Launcher</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Than use `mvn jfx:jar` command to create `javafx jar`. The `jar-file` will be placed at `target/jfx/app`.

If you wish to create a javafx native bundle, use this configuration,

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <vendor>YourCompany</vendor>
        <mainClass>your.package.with.Launcher</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and this  command: `mvn jfx:native`. The native launchers or installers will be placed at `target/jfx/native`.

Answer (score 0):

to create executable jar's of javaFX projects using maven follow this tutorial : [from-zero-to-javafx-in-5-minutes](http://web.archive.org/web/20150319160208/http://www.zenjava.com/2012/11/24/from-zero-to-javafx-in-5-minutes/)

> Using this plugin it’s much, much easier to get up and running quickly
>   and to build complicated distribution bundles (such as executable JAR
>   files, native installers and webstart bundles)